# Effect of atmospheric drag on earth's rotation

Tags: rotation, drag, air

Okay, so I had a question answered regarding the earth rotating and planes flying east and west but one part of the answer talked about how the atmosphere is moving along with the earth (same angular speed). "*if one layer were rotating faster or slower than the other, drag would speed up the slower layer and slow down the faster one.*" Sure, I can see this but it occurred to me that the atmosphere would be acting against the earth's rotation over a sufficiently long period of time. **Is the rotation of the earth slowing down because of atmospheric drag**?

Comment: An answer from NASA? http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/news/topstory/2003/0210rotation.html

Comment: Farcher 20 This could be part of the answer; the article says "the spinning Earth is affected by many factors, including changes in the way the winds blow or currents in the ocean. Some of these factors can act to speed the planet up, while others literally drag it down." However, I'm going to have to think about it a bit since the article says that conservation of angular momentum brings it back into balance as it is all one system. That doesn't help me visualize the effect of 3 billion years of rotation and drag.

Comment: Quoting: "During El Niño years, for example, the rotation of the Earth may slow ever so slightly because of stronger winds, increasing the length of a day by a fraction of a millisecond (thousandth of a second)." and "This graph displays the close connection between the global angular momentum of the atmosphere derived from wind analyses (darker red curve, scale on right) and the observed changes in the length of day (lighter green curve, scale on left), after removing low frequencies, for the years 2000/2001.  "

Comment: The jet stream going from east to west is a consequence of warm air rising near the equator traveling north. Drag has accelerated it to go from W to E, but its velocity exceeds that of the earth's as it moves north, so it goes  ultimately  *faster* than the earth that dragged it!